# Dynamic responseDecodable to handle responses from Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

Please help me, I am writing a class for sending requests to the API. And I ran into the problem of dynamic substitution of the necessary structures for different answers.

I run into an error with different data types. How can this problem be solved?

```
open class Api {
***

    func data (_ method: Methods, _ parameters: (String, Any) ..., callback: @escaping (Any) -> Void) {
        ***
        
        var ofDecodable = [String: Any]()
        
        ofDecodable = [
            "auth.logout": saveResponse.self,
            "playlist.get": dataResponse.self
        ]
        
        let of = ofDecodable[_method].self
        
        AF.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters) // Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
            .responseDecodable(of: of) { response in // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'T.Type'
                switch response.result {
                   case let .success(data):
                        print(data)
                        callback(data)

                   case let .failure(error):
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
    }

}


enum Methods: String {
    case auth_logout = "auth.logout"
    case playlist_get = "playlist.get"
}

public struct saveResponse: Codable  {
    let response: Response
    
    struct Response: Codable {
        let save: String
    }
}

public struct dataResponse: Codable {
    let response: Response
    
    struct Response: Codable {
        let id: String?
        let name: String?
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before and I'm not sure it's possible to make this work cleanly; it's certainly not easy. I've always just added a generic type argument to the API method itself, in much the same way `responseDecodable` does.

Comment: Maybe this can be solved using generics

Comment: Yes, I also think that using generics, but I do not understand how to do it. I'm just starting to learn swift and I don't have enough knowledge of syntax ((

Comment: Then write simpler code, don't try to come up with advanced design solutions if you are a beginner. Instead write simple code that solves the problem and nothing else, you can always come back and make it more generic/reusable later on when you have gained more experience.